# Javascript validation, link together with the form?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I need help to get this working. I have done a script that validate the field "Personalnumber". But i dont know how to link the togheter and get it working.

Can someone help?

//If the form looks weird, i have deleted all the other fields just to get a shorter code.

```
<script>


    function validatePNum(sPNum)
    {
      var numbers = sPNum.match(/^(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)$/);
      var checkSum = 0;

      var d = new Date();
      if (!isDate(sPNum.substring(0,4),sPNum.substring(4,6),sPNum.substring(6,8))) {
        alert("Datumet " + sPNum.substring(0,8) + " är inte korrekt.");
        return false;
      }

      if (numbers == null) { return false; }

      var n;
      for (var i = 3; i <= 12; i++)
      {
        n=parseInt(numbers[i]);
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
          checkSum+=n;
        } else {
          checkSum+=(n*2)%9+Math.floor(n/9)*9
        }
      }

      if (checkSum%10==0) { return true;}
      return false;
    }

    function getYear(y) { return (y < 1000) ? y + 1900 : y; }

    function isDate(year, month, day)
    {
      month = month - 1; // 0-11 in JavaScript
      var tmpDate = new Date(year,month,day);
      if ( (getYear(tmpDate.getYear()) == year) &&
      (month == tmpDate.getMonth()) &&
      (day == tmpDate.getDate()) )
        return true;
      else
        return false;
    }

    </script>
    <form method="post" name="post" action="index.php?site=register">

      <tr>
        <td class="border_1" align="left">Personnummer:</td>
        <td class="border_1"><input id="personalnumber" type="text" name="personalnumber" value="$personalnumber"  size="30"/><small> YYYYMMDDXXXX</small></td>
      </tr>

        <div align="center"><input name="save" type="submit" value="Registera" /></div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Did you try onBlur event or using jQuery to link your code to object? <input type="text" onblur="myFunction()">

Comment: No i havent try that, the problem, is thats i dont know how to write it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all change the `name` in your form to something like `name="myForm"`. Then, you can link your JS code with your form by taking the value of the field, ie `var x = document.forms["myForm"].value;`. Not tested, but this is a way to link your js code with the form in your html.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use jQuery

just add to your form id (like form_id in my example).

`$('#form_id').submit(function(){
  validatePNum(sPNum)
  //do more things
});`